# How to set Adapter to Auto Complete Text view?

Tags: android, search, autocompletetextview

I need adapter data set to the auto complete text view in android .

Answer (score 18):

Create an array of String or get it from any function and create an ArrayAdapter of String then let the adapter to set the list for you .

```
 String[] array={"first","second item" ,"third item"};
 AutoCompleteTextView textView;

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.et_search);


adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(PlayListActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);

                textView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 5):

Create one project for `AutoCompleteTextView` and paste the code to required place -

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   >
<TextView 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/hello"
   />
<AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/myautocomplete"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:completionThreshold="1"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**AutoCompleteTextview.java**

```
public class AndroidAutoCompleteTextView extends Activity implements TextWatcher{

AutoCompleteTextView myAutoComplete;
String item[]={
  "January", "February", "March", "April",
  "May", "June", "July", "August",
  "September", "October", "November", "December"
};

   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);

   myAutoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.myautocomplete);

   myAutoComplete.addTextChangedListener(this);
   myAutoComplete.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, item));

   }

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Just use this example. And, figure out how they're setting adapter to `AutoComplete TextView` Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

**Case: 1 (if array declare in string.xml file then )**

```
string.xml

    <string-array name="units_array">
        <item>Bags</item>
        <item>Box</item>
        <item>Bottles</item>
        <item>Cubic Meter</item>
        <item>Cartons</item>
        <item>Dozens</item>
        <item>Grams</item>
        <item>Kilograms</item>
        <item>Kiloliter</item>
        <item>Kilometre</item>
        <item>Meters</item>
        <item>Metric tons</item>
        <item>Numbers</item>
        <item>Packs</item>
        <item>Pieces</item>
    </string-array>
    
    //MainActivity.Java
    
    String[] UnitList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.units_array);
        ArrayAdapter<String> UnitAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.drop_down_layout, UnitList);
        UnitAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        mBinding.autoCompleteTextViewUnit.setAdapter(UnitAdapter);
```

**Case: 2 (if array declare in MainActivity then)**

```
//MainActivity.Java
        String[] array={"Bags","Box" ,"Bottles","Cubic Meter"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);
        mBinding.autoCompleteTextViewUnit.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**Case: 3 (if array is a API response then)**

```
//MainActivity.Java
        if (!response.getData().isEmpty()) {
            List<ModelClass> responseGroupList = response.getData();
            List<String> UnitList = new ArrayList<>();
            
            for (ModelClass data : responseGroupList) 
            {
                UnitList.add(data.getItemGroup());
            }
            
            ArrayAdapter<String> UnitAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.drop_down_layout, R.id.textView, UnitList);
            UnitAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            mBinding.autoCompleteTextViewUnit.setAdapter(UnitAdapter);
        }
```

*default Select List Item position=0*

```
 mBinding.autoCompleteTextViewUnit.setText(UnitAdapter.getItem(0));
```